# ob_start() output buffering doesn't work with ob_gzhandler compression

Tags: php, caching, gzip, output-buffering

I'm confused about using ob_start and ob_start("ob_gzhandler") functions.
I have a test php script in which I'm trying to implement a simple caching system. Here is the script:

```
<?php

ob_start();

function writeCache($content, $filename) {
  $fp = fopen($filename, 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $content);
  fclose($fp);
}   

function readCache($filename, $expiry) {
if (file_exists($filename)) {
  if ((time() - $expiry) > filemtime($filename))
    return FALSE;
  $cache = file($filename);
  return implode('', $cache);
}
return FALSE;
} 

$headfile='cache/head.cache';
$headtime=86400; //1 day cache
//  check if a valid head cache exists
if (!$head = readCache($headfile,$headtime)) {

$title='testing output buffering in caching';
$description='this page is using ob_start for caching';
$keywords='ob_start,output,buffering';

echo '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />';
echo '<meta name="description" content="'.$description.'" />';
echo '<meta name="keywords" content="'.$keywords.'" />';
echo '<meta name="title" content="'.$title.'" />';
echo '<link rel="icon" href="'.filemtime("favicon.ico").'/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />';
echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="'.filemtime("favicon.ico").'/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>';
echo '<title>'.$title.' </title>';
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/'.filemtime("css/style.php").'/style.php" media="screen" />';
echo '</head>';
echo 'head cached at '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$head = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();
writeCache($head,$headfile);

} 

//body cache
$bodyfile='cache/body.cache';
$bodytime=86400; //1 day cache

//  check if a valid body cache exists
if (!$body = readCache($bodyfile,$bodytime)) {

    echo '<body>';
    echo '<p>this is the body of html doc!</p>';
    echo '<p>this part of page was cached in buffer</p>';
    echo 'body cached at '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $body = ob_get_contents();
   ob_clean();
   writeCache($body,$bodyfile);
}   

//footer cache
$footerfile='cache/footer.cache';
$footertime=86400; //1 day cache

//  check if a valid footer cache exists
if (!$footer = readCache($footerfile,$footertime)) {

    echo '<p>this is a footer section!</p>';
    echo '</body></html>';
    echo 'footer cached at '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');   
    $footer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
    writeCache($footer,$footerfile);
}   
ob_end_clean(); 
echo $head.$body.$footer; 
echo '<p>usual output of data...'.date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Script outputs these lines:

```
head cached at 2012-03-29 19:34:36

this is the body of html doc!

this part of page was cached in buffer
body cached at 2012-03-29 19:34:36

this is a footer section!
footer cached at 2012-03-29 19:34:36

usual output of data...2012-03-29 20:13:59
```

All three cache files are present in cache directory and everything seem to work ok. But before I implemented output buffering into the script I had

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler",9);
```

instead of

```
ob_start();
```

at the beginning of script.

So i used gzip compression on my test page. Now if I try to change ob_start()
 to ob_start("ob_gzhandler",9) I got content type error in my browser and blanc window. Why can't I use not only output buffering, but gzip compression on my page too? Is there a way to organize output buffering caching like this using gzip compression of content too?

Hope someone knows the answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bug in PHP on use of ob_gzhandler, must use ob_flush() or ob_end_flush() with it instead  of ob_end_clean() or ob_get_clean()

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=34071

I start the page with something like this:

```
if(substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')){

    ob_start("ob_gzhandler");

}else{

    ob_start();

}
```

I end the page with this:

```
ob_end_flush();
```

I wrap elements I wanna cache in:

```
ob_start(); and ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: I used curl from the command line to figure out what the problem was and to figure out how to get started in solving the issue. Curl from the command line is an invaluable tool for determining the true output to browsers. Solved many encoding issues and other things with it in the past.

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thanks for the explanation of the problem! Then I'd accept your advise about ob_end_flush and wrapping a cache with thanks!